# SignalR and .NET Client does not work on ASP.NET WebForms page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr

I try to build notifications for dashboard in my WebForms application under .NET 4. I have downloaded SignalR version 1.2 (both .net client and server) and prepared a simple notification example. Unfortunatelly it does not work and I can't figure why. If I type http://myserver.com/notificationSample/signalr/hubs javascript proxy appears and it looks ok.

Take a look at the implementation below, does someone see any bug?

a) Hub implementation

```
[HubName("NewMessage")]
public class NewMessageNotifier : Hub
{
    public void NotifyDashboards()
    {

        Clients.All.NewMessageCreated();
    }
}
```

b) Notification caller (server) ~/Pages/NotificationCaller.aspx

```
public partial class NotificationCaller : Page
{
    private HubConnection connection;
    private IHubProxy proxy;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            connection = new HubConnection( "http://myserver.com/notificationSample" );

            proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy( "NewMessage" );

            connection.Start().Wait();                

    }
    // it is handler for onclick event on Button control
    protected void NotifyDashboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        proxy.Invoke( "NotifyDashboards" ).Wait();
    }
}
```

c) Dashboard (client, listener) ~/Pages/Dashboard.aspx

```
public partial class Dashboard: BasePage
{
    private HubConnection connection;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new HubConnection( "http://myserver.com/notificationSample" );

        var proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("NewMessage");

        proxy.On("NewMessageCreated", ShowNotification);

        connection.Start();
    }

    private void ShowNotification()
    {
        ShowAlert("New message added!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using it in the wrong way

**First** 
both b and c are clients, the server gets started by itself, all you need is to do is to add

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

to the

```
Application_Start
```

method in global.asax

**Second**

if you are going to use a webpage as the client, you should do it from javascript, as what you are doing now will not work because the

```
connection.Start()
```

is async and the request will end before it does anything, and it will not wait for incoming connections because all will be disposed

Now how to do it? it will take many pages here, so here are a few links

[A Simple Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

[The Hubs Server API](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

[The Hubs JavaScript API](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

and in case you missed it, [a video that explains what is SignalR, how it works and a simple app](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-034) which you can find [here](https://github.com/SignalR/Samples)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot and I see now my misunderstanding. I would like to clarify one thing. You said that for webpages I have to use JS so I assume that SignalR .NET client works with technologies like WinForms, SilverLight, WP, WPF, where you can store objects in memory as long as you want. It will not work with WebForms, WebApi and ASP MVC. Is that correct?